# Codenameone: DateTime-Pickcer on Android looks ugly/corrupt

Tags: codenameone

I use DateTime Picker within my Codenameone App. On my Android-Device it looks unreadable - see attached Screenshot. Is there any way to fix this corrupt layout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Date-time is a type that isn't supported on Android. We recommend using separate pickers for date and time to achieve a better UX example. You can detect this using this code (assuming static import of `CN`):

```
if(isNativePickerTypeSupported(PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME)) {
    // ...
}
```